Electromagnetic field of dipole antenna
Why do dipole antennas generate EM waves by alternating electric fields instead of alternating magnetic fields?
Why don't alternating magnetic poles detach the magnetic field like how it can do so with the electric field?

Thinking of electric or magnetic fields as “detaching” from an antenna is a misconception. There were never “attached” so they can’t “detach”.

This question has potential (no pun intended), but what do you mean by electric field radiation vs. magnetic field radiation. Can you describe each, respectively, in terms of a charge separation (electric dipole) and a current (magnetic dipole) as the antenna oscillates?

@Gohster so if the propagating field hits a charged object, (exerting a force on it) the source (antenna) would experience a reactional force?

@JEB all the antennae I know consist of having two arms. those arms have opposite electric charges that alternate. I was just wondering why a solenoid (electromagnet) do the same. also have two pole of charges and alternate under AC.

In a magnetic dipole radiator the current flowing around the loop is going back and forth between the terminals of an ac source, and that accelerating/decelerating motion of charges is the cause of radiation. The antennas you call having "arms"
are called electric dipoles because at dc are (small) capacitors.

While a bit awkwardly phrased it is a good question. All antennas generate both electric and magnetic fields. For practical reasons, it is we who view them as being either electric dipoles or magnetic dipoles.
That we view a solenoid as an approximation to a magnetic dipole and a capacitor as to an electric dipole radiator is due to their low frequency, in fact, dc behavior and not to their radiating fields that contain equally radiated electric and magnetic energies.
It is true that one can conceive, say, a Hertzian dipole defined mathematically as $\mathbf p = q \delta(\mathbf r)e^{\mathfrak j \omega t},$ as two conducting spheres connected by a thin ideal wire with oscillating charges, and this would approximate an electric dipole far away but mathematically that is not necessary and one can just say that we have the solution to the Dirac impulse source (ie., Green's function of the Helmholtz equation) from which we can build up any of the more complicated sources employing the principle of superposition. The same goes for using an ideal  magnetic dipole source.
Furthermore, never think of radiation as a sort of "detachment", there is no detachment. An accelerating charge radiates energy, that is in its nature. In both a solenoid and a capacitor driven by alternating currents or voltages, resp., charges are accelerated and decelerated, so they radiate.

So if a dipole antenna is sending out waves, and it hits a charged object at a instance which made that object move, the antenna will have a equal opposite reaction?

Delayed reaction yes but not equal reaction because the original outgoing wave invariably scatters off the object in many directions and then the scattered and reflected wave also spreads out  from which only a tiny fraction reaches the original antenna. Note too that the electrons (free charges) of the metallic object are moved by the wave and thereby generating the scattered reflected wave, the whole macroscopic object is barely if at all moved by a radiation of normal intensity.

There is magnetic dipole radiation with the electric field given by
\begin{equation}
{\bf E(r)=-{\hat r}\times B}=-\frac{k^2e^{ikr}}{r}
{\bf\hat r}\times\mu.
\end{equation}
